# Git remotes not woring after updating to ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, ssh, git

Since I have updated my ubuntu I get this error if I try to pull. I get this for every project I have on github and bitbucket.

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config line 60: Bad SSH2 cipher spec 'aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc'.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have tried to replace my ssh public keys but it did not help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling OpenSSH solved my problem. I had to first stop the ssh service:

`sudo service ssh stop` and `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh stop` and then remove 
`sudo apt-get --purge remove openssh-client openssh-server` and also install again `sudo apt-get install ssh-client`

Maybe there is a better way, but this helped me.